# Make New Button For Each JSON Object

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to get my app to make a button for each item category from my JSON and set the button image and title in the app remotely. How can I do this so that I can add a new category from my database and in the app it will create a new button for that category with image and title?

Any help is much appreciated.
Unfortunately I don’t have much code at the moment to show.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]
You can simply take a horizontal/vertical linear layout in your xml that will act as a container. Put that LinearLayout in Horizontal or Vertical ScrollView like below.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

In your Activity :

```
for (int i = 0; i < yourArray.length(); i++) {
    Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setId(i);
        btn.setTag(i);
        btn.setText("Button " + (i+1));
        btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp), null, null, null);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("BTN", view.getTag().toString());
            }
        });

        linearLayout.addView(btn);
}
```

Similarly, you can add any view you want in the LinearLayout either horizontally or vertically. Have a look at the attached screenshots.